# Problems using Domain.findBy[property] with GORM standalone

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm working with a project using GORM, without any Grails at all, and I'm having problems when I try to do a findByX. For instance, when I try a

> Country.findByName("Canada")

The project does not compile, and it gives me

> Error:(80, 9) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method app.domain.location.Country#findByName(java.lang.String). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.

Even though the field Name exists.

I'm, however, able to, in CountryService.groovy, define a findByName method this way:

```
@Where({ name == countryName })
static Country findByName(String countryName){
    Country.findAll().first()
}
```

But I don't think that's a good practice at all.

To summarize, Is there a dependency, a configuration, or something whatsoever I need in order to do GORM queries like Domain.findByX()? Or is it impossible using GORM standalone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue isn't that the GORM method doesn't exist (eventually); it's that it doesn't exist at compile-time, and you appear to be using `@CompileStatic` (or have your project configured where that's the default).

From the Grails documentation (which talks about Gorm and CompileStatic):
https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/staticTypeCheckingAndCompilation.html

> One limitation of using CompileStatic is that when you use it you give
>   up access to the power and flexibility offered by dynamic dispatch.
>   For example, in Grails you would not be able to invoke a GORM dynamic
>   finder from a class that is marked with CompileStatic because the
>   compiler cannot verify that the dynamic finder method exists, because
>   it doesn’t exist at compile time.

If you want to use GORM dynamic finders, you will need to turn off `@CompileStatic` for the method/class using those finders.  So either remove the `@CompileStatic` annotation, or add `@CompileDynamic`

Other relevant:

- [When/why would I want to use Groovy's @CompileStatic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609130/when-why-would-i-want-to-use-groovys-compilestatic)
- http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html

Answer (score 0):

Using a Data Service is definitely a good idea, though your example would be better written as an `interface` rather than a `class`, without an implementation or the `@Where` annotation and without being static.

```
@Service(Country)
interface ICountryDataService {
    Country findByName(String name)
}
```

The parameter to the method definition should have the same name as the field in the domain class. As long as the return value is not a collection it will return the first one that it finds.

The `@Where` annotation is useful when the query gets more complicated:

```
@Service(Country)
interface ICountryDataService {
    @Where({ name ==~ pattern })
    List<Country> searchCountriesByPattern(String pattern)

    Country findByName(String name)
}
```